# Manual update fails on server

Tags: server, manual-updates

I tried up update to the latest Craft, but assets are not loading and the process stops here.

I deleted the `storage/runtime` folder but I got no luck.

[image]

[image]

Log says:

```
2016/11/08 20:17:23 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /var/www/dev/craft/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/, but could not.
```

It doesn't matter if I set it to 777 or correct user.

Even stranger is that dispite the error log, I get content created in the compiled_templates folder.

Comment: Are those 500 Internal Server Errors or something else?  Anything useful being logged in your web server's error logs?

Comment: Yes, 500 errors. Regular PHP error logging works, a syntax error gets logged, but not the Craft errors. No phperror in the Craft storage either.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. It was super unexpected, after turning on errors finally, I got

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Craft\AppPathCacheDependency' not found in
```

Then I realized that GIT didn't include that file, still not sure why, but now I know the cause.